# ECL YouTube Provider extension

Tags: ecl, extension-errors

I followed the below steps in order to configure ECL YouTube Provider extension
Videos are not loading 
“application/externalcontentlibrary” MIME type i have created with an extension which i uploaded "m2v"
Can you please help me in resolving the issue

thanks in advance

Step1: Copied the dlls provided in the given path C:\ProgramData\SDL\SDL Tridion\External Content Library\AddInPipeline\Addins\YouTubeProvider.

Step 2: updated ExternalContentLibrary.xml as below.

```
           <MountPoints>  
         <MountPoint type="YouTubeProvider" version="*" id="youtube" rootItemName="YouTube">
        <StubFolders>
            <StubFolder id="tcm:714-17438-2" />
        </StubFolders>
        <PrivilegedUserName>Domain\Username</PrivilegedUserName>
        <AppName xmlns="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">MyApp</AppName>
        <DeveloperKey xmlns="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">Got it from devloper account</DeveloperKey>
        <Username xmlns="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">My Test account</Username>
        <Password xmlns="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">My test pass word</Password>
        <UserToDisplay xmlns="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">My another email id</UserToDisplay>
    </MountPoint>
```

Step 4: Created an MIME type “application/externalcontentlibrary” with an extension “m2v”

Step 5: restarted Tridion Service Host.

You tube Mount Point is visible in Tridion. Whereas videos are not loading from the above account.

Comment: It might be an idea to make it clearer what you mean with "videos are not loading". Do they not display in the CME tree, do they display but you do not get thumbnails in the list. Or no thumbnails if you open the item in the CME. Or no videos when you publish? Or something else? :)

Answer (score 8):

In step 4 you must use the extension "ecl" for the application/externalcontentlibrary MIME type. This extension is used internally in ECL.

Comment: Thank You Lars I am able to See YouTube Icon,when I click on that icon videos are not displayed in CMS Tree.
I have updated that extension,and restarted Trdion Service Host.
Still I am having the same issue.